# How to properly generate a WSSE Password Digest in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, base64, sha1, wsse

I'm looking at building a REST API in Symfony2, and in their [Custom Authentication Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) they show how to build a WSSE authentication system, which should be fine for what I need to do. I'm going to start off by building and testing the API through cURL, so I need to be able to quickly generate the headers. I found a [JS generator](http://www.teria.com/~koseki/tools/wssegen/) that showed the headers I would need.

From what I read, the Password Digest should be a base64 encoded SHA1 of the nonce, timestamp, and user password concatenated together in that order. I started with the following data:

```
$nonce = '4c5625ec7af5bdff';
$timestamp = '2013-04-03T04:46:19Z';
$password = 'mypass';
```

and generated the digest:

```
$digest = base64_encode(sha1($nonce.$timestamp.$password));
```

What I don't understand is that the `$digest` variable is now set to `YTgxMDUzOWQzMDBiZmU1MmI2NWQ0YjYwNDc3ZmY5OWI3MmVlZTQyNA==`, but the sample PasswordDigest from the JS generator comes up as `qBBTnTAL/lK2XUtgR3/5m3Lu5CQ=`. I must be missing a step somewhere, but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like I need to use the binary SHA1 result, not the hex representation. My digest should look like this:

```
$digest = base64_encode(sha1($nonce.$timestamp.$password, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post, just tumbled on this post, recently I have developed API in symfony2 with WSSE authentication and this is how I generated full WSSE header with the help of below function:

```
public static function getWsseHeader($username, $apikey, $created, $nonce)
    {

        $digest = sha1($nonce.$created.$apikey, true);

        return sprintf(
            'X-WSSE: UsernameToken Username="%s", PasswordDigest="%s", Nonce="%s", Created="%s"',
            $username,
            base64_encode($digest),
            base64_encode($nonce),
            $created
        );
    }
```